# How to manipulate a pointer to TableView model?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

When it´s necessary manipulate a model of a TableView, it's necessary to get this model using the function `tableView->model()` . But, this returns a pointer to an `QAbstractItem`, and it's necessary one to a `QAbstractModel`.

So... I convert, using a dynamic cast, as shown bellow:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = dynamic_cast <QStandardItemModel*>
                                   (mWidgets->tableView->model());
```

But, this pointer returns NULL and I can't find out why.

Is there some initialization necessary?

Comment: dynamic_cast will return NULL if there is not a shared inheritance hierarchy between the pointer and the pointer type you cast to.

Comment: But... the function tableView->model() returns a pointer to QAbstractItemModel, which is inheritance for QStandardItemModel, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTableView::model()` returns whatever model you gave it with `QTableView::setModel()`, it doesn't have one until you give it one.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! It's clear now: in my constructor class, I just added these lines: 
QStandardItemModel*  model; 
model = new QStandardItemModel(); 
mWidgets->tableView ->setModel(model); 

So, now, I have gave a model to my TableView and everything works correctly!